# NLTK: Adding two values for a feature in FCFG

Tags: python, nltk, context-free-grammar

For NLTK's Feature Grammar, how do I add more than one value for a feature.
E.g. Currently I'm able to successfully use the following,

`NP[TYPE=name]`

I want something like,

`NP[TYPE=[name,organisation,location]]`

That is, `NP` should be able to take values whose type are either name, organisation or location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One "hack" is to convert the feature values into a "one-hot" vector of booleans, e.g.

Instead of this:

```
NP[TYPE=[name,organisation,location]]
```

you can do this:

```
NP[NAME='1',ORG='1',LOC='1']
```

Another e.g., instead of this:

```
NP[TYPE=[name,organisation]
```

you can do this with underspecification:

```
NP[NAME='1',ORG='1']
```

or if you like to overspecify:

```
NP[NAME='1',ORG='1', LOC='0']
```

## EDITED

You can also use the +/- syntax in the feature structure, e.g.

```
NP[+NAME, -ORG, +LOC]
```

For more details, see http://www.nltk.org/book/ch09.html#code-slashcfg

Comment: Instead of specifically giving a boolean value, I wrote NP[+NAME, -ORG]. Worked like a charm. Thanks.